# Find position of sublists containing a given element at nth position

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, searching

I have a list of lists similar to this:

```
L = {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"x", "c", "y"}, {"i", "j", "h"}, {"x", "b", "z"}}
```

Each list within `L` happens to be of length 3. Suppose I need to find the position of the lists that have a particular element (say, "b") at the $n^{th}$ position. How can I do this efficiently?

Currently, I have an approach that works but I don't think it is very efficient inefficient (it creates a new list with the $n^{th}$ elements and then looks for the queried element, I'm sure there's a way to search `L` directly):

```
queriedElement = "b";

queriedPosition = 2;

occurencePositions = Flatten@Position[#[[queriedPosition]] & /@ L, queriedElement]//AbsoluteTiming
```

Which gives the correct answer:

```
{0.000035, {1, 4}}
```

Searching for an alternative efficient way because I need to do this in large lists.

Thanks!

Comment: As shown by kglr, `Position[L[[All,2]], "b"]` is probably close to the 'canonical' solution, and it might be of interest that if you don't Flatten, the result may be used directly with `Extract` to obtain the full sublists, if desired: `Extract[L,%]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Flatten @ Position[L, _List?(#[[2]] === "b" &)]
```

> ```
> {1, 4}
> ```

Making it a function:

```
posF1 = Flatten @ Position[#, _List?(Function[x, x[[#2]] === #3])] &;

posF1[L, 2, "b"]
```

> ```
>  {1, 4}
> ```

Alternatively,

```
posF2 = Flatten @ Position[#[[All, #2]], #3] &;

posF2[L, 2, "b"]
```

> ```
>  {1, 4}
> ```

Also

```
posF3 = PositionIndex[#[[All, #2]]]@#3 &;

posF3[L, 2, "b"]
```

> ```
>  {1, 4}
> ```

Comment: As you are comparing against a string, it is better to use `===` instead of `==`: `#[[2]] === "b"`.

Comment: Thank you @J.M. Edited to change `==` to `===`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a solution with `Pick`.

```
f[v_,p_,e_]:=Pick[Range[Length[v]], v[[All, p]], e]
```

where `v` is your `L`, `p` is your `queriedPosition` and `e` is your `queriedElement`.

Here is a timing test of `Pick`, along with the functions from @kglr.

```
Block[{element, position, list, posF1, posF2, posF3},
   element = "a";
   position = 1;
   posF1 = Flatten@Position[#, _List?(Function[x, x[[#2]] === #3])] &;
   posF2 = Flatten@Position[#[[All, #2]], #3] &;
   posF3 = PositionIndex[#[[All, #2]]]@#3 &;
   list = RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a", "j"], {2000, 3}];
   First /@ {
      RepeatedTiming[f[list, position, element]],
      RepeatedTiming[posF3[list, position, element]],
      RepeatedTiming[posF2[list, position, element]],
      RepeatedTiming[Flatten@Position[list, _List?(#[[position]] === element &)]],
      RepeatedTiming[posF1[list, position, element]]
   }
]
```

Sample output:

> {0.000125, 0.000200, 0.0002303, 0.00248, 0.0030}